# display all the date between two date with data

Tags: sql-server

I got the following code from this forum.It retrieve data from staff attendance from the table like:

```
   userid dateandtime checktype 
1. 100    01/01/2015  I
2. 100    01/01/2015  O
3. 102    02/02/2015  I
4. 102    02/02/2015  O
```

Now I want to retrieve all the data between two specific date but all the date should be retrieved even one absent and these days should show blank or zero in the column of hours

```
SELECT  t.UserID ,
        [Date] = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, t.CheckIn)) ,
        CheckIn = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t.CheckIn, 108) ,
        CheckOut = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t.CheckOut, 108) ,
        [Hours] = CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t.CheckIn, t.CheckOut) / 60. AS DECIMAL(10,
                                                              2))
FROM    ( SELECT    t.UserID ,
                    CheckIn = t.Checktime ,
                    CheckOut = r.Checktime ,
                    RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY t.UserID,
                                                 r.Checktime ORDER BY 1 / 0 )
          FROM      CHECKINOUT t
                    OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1
                                            *
                                  FROM      CHECKINOUT t2
                                  WHERE     t2.UserID = t.UserID
                                            AND t2.Checktime > t.Checktime
                                            AND DATEADD(dd, 0,
                                                        DATEDIFF(dd, 0,
                                                              t.Checktime)) = DATEADD(dd,
                                                              0,
                                                              DATEDIFF(dd, 0,
                                                              t2.Checktime))
                                            AND t2.Checktype = 'O'
                                  ORDER BY  t2.Checktime
                                ) r
          WHERE     t.Checktype = 'I'
        ) t
WHERE   t.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want. The result provided is from this statement? Or the statement is on top of that result. What is `all the data`? Provide sample input and sample output that you want

Comment: it retrieves the data only staff's in/out he punched, when I retrieving one staff's data it did not show the absent date, I need to display all the date between two date using the above code including staff's in/out log